# Unable to install dplyr package on windows vista

Tags: r, package, dplyr

I'm trying to install the *dplyr* package on my Windows vista machine (through R Studio). I have the latest version of R installed (3.22) and the preview version of R Studio installed. I've had no issues in the past installing packages, however when I try to install this one, I got error:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘BH’

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/BH_1.58.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 13846694 bytes (13.2 MB)
downloaded 13.2 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/dplyr_0.4.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2552598 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB
```

I also tried installing the *devtools* package so that I could install the *dplyr* package straight from github. However, the devtools package also gave me trouble on installation:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘BH’, ‘brew’, ‘xml2’, ‘httr’, ‘curl’, ‘memoise’, ‘whisker’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rversions’, ‘git2r’

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/BH_1.58.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 13846694 bytes (13.2 MB)
downloaded 13.2 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/brew_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 104730 bytes (102 KB)
downloaded 102 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/xml2_0.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3174710 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/httr_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 382429 bytes (373 KB)
downloaded 373 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/curl_0.9.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4384906 bytes (4.2 MB)
downloaded 4.2 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/memoise_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16878 bytes (16 KB)
downloaded 16 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/whisker_0.3-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 64756 bytes (63 KB)
downloaded 63 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/jsonlite_0.9.17.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1009755 bytes (986 KB)
downloaded 986 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/roxygen2_4.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 594453 bytes (580 KB)
downloaded 580 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/rversions_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16455 bytes (16 KB)
downloaded 16 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/git2r_0.11.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2690457 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.9.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 357684 bytes (349 KB)
downloaded 349 KB
```

None of these files ever get written into ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’.

Other things tried:

- making sure that I have the latest version of R installed
- opening R Studio in Administrator mode and installing the packages then
- installing in R commander instead
- trying a different CRAN mirror

None of these helped.

Any ideas how to install dplyr?

Comment: Does it give you any error messages?

Comment: No, just prints out what I've posted.

Comment: Could you check `packageVersion("dplyr")` and see what it returns

Comment: It prints "Error in packageVersion("dplyr") : package 'dplyr' not found."

Comment: It really doesn't print anything after downloading the packages? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: I don't think it ever actually gets to the state of downloading dplyr. I can't find it in the directory it's supposed to be installing to, and I can't load it afterward (via the library function).

Comment: You could try downloading the tar/zip files to your local machine, and installing locally, perhaps with a call like utils::install.packages("c:/R/dplyrversion.zip", repos=NULL) from Rstudio

Comment: Downloading is the first step and only if that's sucessfull it starts installing. However, you should see error messages if you didn't interrupt R manually.

Comment: Thanks @erasmortg, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@erasmortg suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858446/unable-to-install-dplyr-package-on-windows-vista?noredirect=1#comment53553298_32858446), I first downloaded the dplyr zip file from the [cran-r page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html). Then ran:

```
utils::install.packages("c:/R/dplyrversion.zip", repos=NULL)
```

Comment: when you do this _by hand_ you have to manually download all the dependencies. Is there a way to avoid that ?